# Getting an SQL statement to output a table in a certain order

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm doing a test web shop that has sections within sections. There can be an unlimited number of levels so I have just one table `Section`.

The table has the following columns:

`SectionID, SectionTitle,  SectionLevel, ParentID, PageOrder`

SectionLevel: 1 being topmost (no parent)

PageOrder: Within it's parent group, which order it should go in.

And for test data :

```
SectionID  SectionTitle  SectionLevel  ParentID  PageOrder
---------  ------------  ------------  --------  ---------
2          Ladies        1             0         2
3          Mens          1             0         3
4          Jewellery     2             2         1 
5          Clothing      2             2         2
6          Clothing      2             3         1 
7          Accessories   2             3         2
```

I want to return this data in one table so that the first top level section is first, and then all of it's children's sections are next, and then the second top level section etc.

I've had a play around with it but can't get to come out right. I think that it should be possible to do it if I redesigned the table but can't think how.

The data should come back in the following order:

```
SectionID  SectionTitle  SectionLevel  ParentID  PageOrder
---------  ------------  ------------  --------  ---------
2          Ladies        1             0         2
4          Jewellery     2             2         1 
5          Clothing      2             2         2
3          Mens          1             0         3
6          Clothing      2             3         1 
7          Accessories   2             3         2
```

Comment: Simple hack based on that data: `ORDER BY ParentID, PageOrder`

Comment: That's what I tried first, but then you get the top three sections first and then the child sections.

Comment: That won't work, as 2 and 3 would show up first.  OP wants to nest them, I believe.  How many levels deep can it go?  If it's infinite, that will be a little trickier than if you know it's always two levels.

Comment: Yeah it is infinite. Think that is why I'm having a problem with it!

Comment: In which case `ORDER BY (10000*ISNULL(ParentID,0))+PageOrder` would be an even uglier hack to try.  There's an underlying problem here, with unlimited nesting as a requirement, there's not a neat SQL query for it.  With two or three levels you could do it, but it would be a little messy.  You could process it in code easily enough recursively.  That's the best solution in this case I think.

Comment: this a classic tree sort

Comment: If you are using Microsoft SQL Server (2005 or newer) you can use a [recursive common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to output them into a table on a asp.net webpage, but figured if I could it into one statement I could use a DataGridView. Would the best thing to do would be to to do a select * and just insert the table rows accordingly as I read them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is deliberately slightly niaive to make it easier on my fingers.  It can be tuned if necessary to allow more nodes in the tree to be accomodated.

```
DECLARE
  @maxPageOrder INT,
  @maxLevel     INT,
  @multiplier   INT

SELECT
  @maxPageOrder  = MAX(PageOrder) + 1,
  @maxLevel      = MAX(SectionLevel)
FROM
  Section

SELECT
  @multiplier = POWER(@maxPageOrder, @maxLevel - 1)    
;

WITH
  recursed_tree
AS
(
  SELECT
    SectionID                      AS SectionID,
    PageOrder * @multiplier        AS finalOrder,
    @multiplier / @maxPageOrder    AS multiplier
  FROM
    Section
  WHERE
    ParentID = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    child.SectionID,
    parent.finalOrder + child.PageOrder * parent.multiplier,
    parent.multiplier / @maxPageOrder
  FROM
    recursed_tree  AS parent
  INNER JOIN
    Section        AS child
      ON child.ParentID = parent.SectionID
)

SELECT
  Section.*
FROM
  Section
INNER JOIN
  recursed_tree
    ON Section.SectionID = recursed_tree.SectionID
ORDER BY
  recursed_tree.finalOrder
```

Note: This assumes all page orders start from 1, rather than 0.

Comment: It is 'n' levels deep. I did say 'There can be an unlimited number of levels ' but only put up a few as an example.

Comment: @Adringer, as people are suggesting, there's not a general query for that.

Comment: Many thanks for that answer, but I'm having a little trouble getting it to run. It's complaining about needing a semi-colon before With and have tried putting it in but then it has a problem with the last line. I've never had experience with WITH or SQL Recursion so please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: Indeed, the `;` is needed, sorry about that.  What is the error you now get?  (And I assumed you're using SQL Server because of the ASP tag, but what version are you using?)

Comment: I found it, I used recurrsed, recurssed and probably a few other things.  The CTE needs the same name all through the code, not my typo magic versions :)

Comment: Thought I had double checked the spelling before I posted! I appreciate your help very much, but I appear to be getting duplicate rows when returning the results.

Comment: Okay, my mistake again, I missed a WHERE clause in the first SELECT.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was trying to get! I really appreciate you taking your time to help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH tree (SectionID, ParentID, SectionLevel, SectionTitle) AS
(
    SELECT SectionID, ofs.ParentID, ofs.SectionLevel, ofs.SectionTitle
     FROM Section ofs
     WHERE ofs.ParentID = 0
     ORDER BY SectionID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SectionID, ofs.ParentID, ofs.SectionLevel, ofs.SectionTitle
      FROM Section ofs
      JOIN tree ON tree.ID = ofs.ParentID
      ORDER BY PageOrder
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the messy solution I was talking about..

```
select
    a.SectionID, a.SectionTitle, a.SectionLevel, a.ParentID, a.PageOrder
from
    section a
    left outer join section b on b.SectionID=a.ParentID
    left outer join section c on c.SectionID=b.ParentID
order by
    c.PageOrder, b.PageOrder, a.PageOrder
```

As I mentioned in the comment, better to do it in code.. this is only for 3 levels (you could make it more by adding another outer join and order by clause).

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated in SQL. If you have access to Safari Books, there are some relevant sections in *Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties*.